# Where exactly do my blood echoes go when I die?

Tags: bloodborne

I've died kind of a lot and I'm finding that relocating my lost blood echoes has been a bit unpredictable. Sometimes, they're laying on the ground where I died. Other times, I get them back after killing the enemy that killed me. Yet other times, I seem to get them back after killing a random enemy that wasn't anywhere near where I died.

How, exactly, does blood echo recovery work?

Comment: I've noticed that the blood stain left on the ground is a lot harder to see than it was before. The effect that swirls up isn't green, it's more of a faded red and it blends in with the environment really well.

Comment: I agree, but I know I've definitely gotten my souls back on a kill rather than picking them up off the ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enemies can now contain your blood echoes, so to get them back you need to kill that enemy.

I have just started the game myself and haven't noticed this yet, but after researching it appears this is actually a new mechanic in the game. It looks like the enemy has to be near where you died, and can be seen to have glowing eyes (see [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/3096mb/i_think_i_understand_how_blood_echoes_upon_death/)).

One poster says:

> Yeah it actually says this in the manual. Something like 'your blood echoes will be on the ground unless an enemy gets to them first... which will make them have glowing blue eyes... kill them to regain your lost blood echoes'.

Comment: I wonder if bosses can pick them up. That idea is frightening.

Comment: I was thinking that too. It's cool they've changed the retrieval system in this game. Cool avatar by the way!

Comment: Make sure you also look at this: [Lost All My Blood Echoes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212580/lost-all-my-blood-echoes)

Comment: I've fought about 4 bosses and none of them have picked up my Blood Echoes yet.