# Can't find blood echoes after dying and signing off

Tags: bloodborne

I had 50,000 blood echoes and died.  I had other matters to attend to so I decided that I would just sign out and come back later to retrieve them.  I go back to the scene of the crime and there was no blood stain... nothing... I killed all enemies in the area, hoping one of them stole them... no luck.  I did not die a second time so there is no way I lost them that way.  Any idea how I can retrieve my lost blood echoes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I stumbled across this [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/30kmub/psa_exiting_the_game_causes_you_to_lose_any_blood/) and it turns out multiple players have also experienced this. Turns out there is a way to retrieve your blood echoes.  Go to the [Lecture Building](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Lecture+Building) and, for some unexplained reason, your blood echoes will be in the room adjacent to the bonfire. I really hope this helps someone out in the future. Happy hunting!

---

Update:

I did a little experiment where I intentionally died, exited the game and continued.  I can confirm that regardless of where you died, you can ***always*** go back to the Lecture Building (1st Floor) and find your blood echoes waiting for you.

Comment: I confirm this. I`ve seen my echoes there on the 1st floor, though I didn't understand why. I didn't die in this location.

Comment: This is really interesting! I'm guessing there is some lore-based explanation for it.

Comment: What if you haven't gotten far enough to have access to that room yet?

Answer (score 0):

You might now want to kill any boss, or you won't find them — at least that's what happened for me. I died to a chalice boss, signed off, came back the next day, and one-shot the boss. Echoes were not in the room. I searched the Internet, found that post, and went to the Lecture Building first floor, but echoes were nowhere to be found.